# Firebase Cloud messaging not work when app kill from background

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use FCM to push notification from firebase console but notification doesn't appear when app is kill from the background

Comment: Which payload are you using? You should use _Data_ payload.

Comment: @Piyush thank you so much for your comment. I tried already with Data payload but it doesn't show notification when app remove from background. I already tried with push notification from Firebase console and rest api but it doesn't work.